# Specify some (but not all) constructor parameters at runtime

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

Suppose I have the following service interfaces defined (as well as implementations):

```
interface Service1 { /* Methods omitted for brevity */ }
interface Service2 { /* Methods omitted for brevity */ }
```

I also have this interface that cannot be modified (it's out of my hands):

```
interface YouAreNotAllowedToModifyMe {
  Object createSomething();
}
```

Further suppose that I have a class that implements the `YouAreNotAllowedToModifyMe` interface and accepts implementations of those services along with the current `HttpServletRequest`. Note that the request is an implementation detail and NOT part of the interface.

```
class Demo implements YouAreNotAllowedToModifyMe {

  private final HttpServletRequest request;
  private final Service1 service1;
  private final Service2 service2;

  @Inject
  public Demo(HttpServletRequest request, Service1 service1, Service2 service2) {
    this.request = request;
    this.service1 = service1;
    this.service2 = service2;
  }

  public Object createSomething() {
    // Use the request, service1, and service2 in order to create the object.
  }
}
```

`Demo` cannot be instantiated until runtime because it requires the current `HttpServletRequest`, however I would like CDI injection to take care of injecting the other parameters. How can I do that?

Essentially, I would like for this to be possible (it's not):

```
class Foo {

  @Inject
  private final Instance<Demo> demoInstance;

  public void doSomething(HttpServletRequest request) {

    // This is pretend. This won't really work, though I wish it would.
    // Essentially, I pass in the request and CDI takes care of everything else.
    Demo demo = demoInstance.get(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: A request is a one-off object and usually matches more naturally with a method parameter than an object field.

Comment: @chrylis I agree with you completely, however, I oversimplified the code in order to keep it concise. In reality, the `Demo` class (not the real name) implements an interface that I'm not at liberty to change. The method on that interface does not accept the request. That is just a detail of my particular implementation.

Comment: I have updated the question in order to better demonstrate the situation.

Comment: So perhaps what you need is something like a request-scoped bean?

Comment: I'm new to CDI injection, does a request-scoped bean already exist? What would that look like? How would I get access to the request?

Comment: I use Spring rather than the CDI knockoff, but I'd suggest starting with the docs for `@RequestScoped`.

Comment: *implements an interface that I'm not at liberty to change.*, everything can be solved with an additional layer of indirection ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** use a constructor with half arguments injected and half provided by hand. You have however alternatives:

- Create a producer for the `HttpServletRequest`. Better yet, use [Delta Spike](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/servlet.html). Then you can actually *inject* the `HttpServletRequest`!
- Modify `Demo` to be a *factory* for instances of `YouAreNotAllowedToModifyMe`, rather than implementing it:

  ```
  @ApplicationScoped //probably-but not necessarily???
  public class Demo {
      @Inject
      private final Service1 service1;
      @Inject
      private final Service2 service2;

      public YouAreNotAllowedToModifyMe makeYouAreNotAllowedToModifyMe(HttpServletRequest request) {
          return new YouAreNotAllowedToModifyMeImpl(request);
      }

      private class YouAreNotAllowedToModifyMeImpl implements YouAreNotAllowedToModifyMe {
          YouAreNotAllowedToModifyMeImpl(HttpServletRequest request) {
              // do what you must...
          }

          // implement it!
          // remember, you can actually use service1 &
          // service 2 from the enclosing instance
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the definitive answer. That prevented me from continuing down a path that wouldn't work. I'm coming back to Java after having been a full-time JavaScript developer for the past 2.5 years using Angular.js. In Angular.js, you actually can do half and half (using locals). See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#instantiate. I just assumed that something like that would be possible in CDI as well.